# HDMI port not working after installing KDE Desktop Environment for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, xorg, graphics, xrandr, hdmi

My laptop can't detect the  HDMI port and my Samsung TV shows no signal. When I run `xrandr`, my HDMI port doesn't show in the output.

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       59.6*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: @Gilles I have "Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller"

Answer (score 1):

On television, go to Menu -> Input -> Edit name -> HDMI and set it to `PC` or `DVI PC`.

Comment: How will changing the name make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

This guy had a similar problem, and solved it by installing Intel graphics drivers.

[hdmi not showing up in xrandr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188531/hdmi-not-showing-up-in-xrandr)

Which are, if I'm not mistaken, in the official repos, so a simple

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem on my Dell G3, running Kubuntu 20.04 with a NVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti. But in my case, "xrandr -q" showed "HDMI-1 disconnected".

Maybe the solution I've used apply to you as well. First uninstall all nvidia drivers, using:

```
sudo apt remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
```

Then, after restarting, install the latest nvidia driver, which at the time I was writing this was:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
```

If you have a different graphic card, edit the commands to fit your case.

Hope it helps.