# hdmi not showing up in xrandr

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, monitors, xrandr, hdmi

Everything used to work until recently. Now, whenever I connect my HDMI monitor to my laptop nothing happens. Running xrandr doesn't show the HDMI output. Can anyone help out? I've been trying to fix this for the last 3 hours. I even reinstalled unity but that didn't work.

I'm on 14.04 ubuntu.

Any help is appreciated!!

Vladimir

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1360 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
       1920x1080      60.1 +   59.9     40.0  
       1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
       1600x1024      60.2  
       1400x1050      60.0  
       1280x1024      60.0  
       1440x900       59.9  
       1280x960       60.0  
       1360x768       59.8*    60.0  
       1152x864       60.0  
       1024x768       60.0  
       800x600        60.3     56.2  
       640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a sleepless night of googling and trying things out (like reinstalling unity and the x drivers), I decided to try out Intel's approach. Apparently they officially support linux and they have a graphics driver installer (link below). After downloading and installing everything started working again.

I'm in Ubuntu heaven again.

Enjoy!

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7

Comment: I had the same problem, but fixed it by booting into another distro that used a different version of `XRandR` to 'turing on HDMI' there then rebooting back into the problematic distro.  I think the intel graphics driver must have some setting that persists across boots that causes the HDMI to be hidden.

Comment: I had a similar issue on Arch/Antergos recently. Reinstalling the Intel drivers `xf86-video-intel` fixed it for me.